# in ns2 ospf what does 'mt' mean in most code

Tags: ns2, ospf, mt

In origin code in ospf in ns2, what does '`mt`' mean? Does it mean any middle node in the path? Or means multi-topo, which means it contains all middle nodes.

eg: in   `ospf.cc`

```
OspfPaths::iterator OspfPaths::insertPath(int destId, int mtid, int cost, int nextHop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read ospf.h for descriptions ...

```
71  //**********************************************************************************
72  // MTLink: representing MultiTopology id and metric attached to a link
73  //**********************************************************************************

78      int mtId_; // MultiTopology id

90  //**********************************************************************************
91  // MTLinkList: List of MTLink attached to a link
92  //**********************************************************************************

111     MTLinkList MTLinkList_; //MT id's and metrics attached to the link

292     int mtId_; // multiTopology id
372     // lookup the path's cost for the destId and Mtid
385     // lookup next hop list for the destId and Mtid
439     // insert next hop list for destId and mtid
463     // returns the iterator for the less cost path for mtid
1084        // returns the path for destId and Mtid
```